# Kinetic Energy of a Symmetric Dumb-Bell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> Consider the system consisting of the *symmetric* dumb-bell (two particles each of mass $m$ connected by a light, inextensible rod of length $l$) moving in the plane. Use as coordinates the angle $\phi$ between the rod and the $x$-direction, and the Cartesian coordinates of the centre of mass of the dumb-bell.
>
> Write down the expression for the kinetic energy of this system in these coordinates and find the mass-inertia matrix for this system, showing that it is non degenerate.

**My attempt at solving this problem was as follows:**

\begin{align}
x&=\frac{l}{2}\cos{\phi} \\
y&=\frac{l}{2}\sin{\phi}
\end{align}

Then $T=\frac{1}{2}(2m)(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)=m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$ so
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=-\frac{l}{2}\sin{\phi}\dot{\phi} \\
\dot{y}&=\frac{l}{2}\cos{\phi}\dot{\phi}
\end{align}

From this we have that
\begin{align}
T&=m\left\{\left(-\frac{l}{2}\sin{\phi}\dot{\phi}\right)^2+\left(\frac{l}{2}\cos{\phi}\dot{\phi}\right)^2 \right\}
\\&=m\left(\frac{l^2}{4}\sin^2{\phi}\dot{\phi^2}+\frac{l^2}{4}\cos^2{\phi}\dot{\phi^2}\right)
\\&=\frac{ml^2}{4}\dot{\phi^2}(\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi})
\\&=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{l^2}{2}\dot{\phi^2}\right),
\end{align}
which gives the mass-inertia matrix as
$$
\mathbb{K}=\left( \begin{matrix} 0&0\\ 0&\frac{ml^2}{2} \end{matrix} \right),
$$
which is clearly a *degenerate* matrix.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for with this problem?

Comment: I think you're forgetting the possibility that the center of mass is also moving, ie, your definition of kinetic energy only includes rotational energy, not translational energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to include the motion of the center of mass of the system. As the problem says, use the angle $\phi$ and the Cartesian coordinates $\textit{of the CM}$. The kinetic energy should instead be $T = \frac{1}{2} I \dot{\phi}^2 + m(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)$